# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Path not found

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

In my WPF Application i can use this command:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\appwiz.cpl");
```

But this is not working:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\firewall.cpl");
```

i got (in german): System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden". File not found. But when i put `C:\Windows\System32\firewall.cpl` to my file Explorer, Firewall.cpl is opening.
I tryed some others:

OK:

- desk.cpl
- hdwwiz.cpl
- inetcpl.cpl
- intl.cpl
- joy.cpl
- main.cpl
- mmsys.cpl

NOK:

- Firewall.cpl
- igfxCPL.cpl
- compmgmtlauncher.exe

What ist the Problem?

Comment: may you need admin rights

Comment: This seems related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374030/system-componentmodel-win32exception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specifi

Comment: c:\windows\sysnative\firewall.cpl or Project > Properties > Build tab, "Prefer 32-bit" unticked.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Comment: c:\windows\sysnative\firewall.cpl  is working fine for me, whit or whitout admin rights. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments,the solution is `c:\windows\sysnative\firewall.cpl` or `Project > Properties > Build tab`, `"Prefer 32-bit"` unticked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

You can also refer to the two answers under this link.

[how do i link my windows form with .NET framework to steam without build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72538922/16764901)